# dotnet pack multiple projects into one package

Tags: nuget-package, dotnet-core-pack

I have a build pipeline that is building multiple library files in a single solution. In the YML file I have the following task to package the dlls;

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Create nuget packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: 'Framework/**/*.csproj;!**/*.Test.csproj'
    packDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/packages/nuget'
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: 'byBuildNumber'
```

This creates all my library files as seperate *nupkg* files. I would like them in one nupkg file.

Is this possible using `dotnet pack`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way of doing that is to create a [nuspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec) that includes outputs of the csproj you want to bundle since the pack command only accepts a single project.

You can also use the [dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies) attribute to link to other nupkg instead of bundling them.